# Scala implicit conversion of type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, type-parameter

I'm trying to create a library that can convert distances from one unit into another. Ideally I'd be able to specify a distance in one unit, and when passed to a method that requires a different unit, have the scala compiler convert it automatically. This is what I have so far:

```
abstract class BaseUnit(scale: Option[Double] = None) {
  def unit: String

  def scalingFactor: Double = scale match {
    case Some(factor) => factor
    case None => 1.0
  }
}

object Cm {
  implicit def inch2cm(inch: Inch):Cm = new Cm(Some(0.393 * inch.scalingFactor))
}

class Cm(scale: Option[Double] = None) extends BaseUnit(scale) {
  def unit: String = "cm"
}

object Inch {
  implicit def cm2inch(cm: Cm):Inch = new Inch(Some(2.54 * cm.scalingFactor))
}

class Inch(scale: Option[Double] = None) extends BaseUnit(scale) {
  def unit: String = "inch"
}

class Distance[A <: BaseUnit](val scalar: Double, val unit: A) {
  override def toString: String = (scalar*unit.scalingFactor)+unit.unit
}


def foo(x: Distance[Cm], y: Distance[Cm]): String = x.toString()+","+y.toString()
```

Using it without explicitly stating the type parameter seems to make Scala use the `Nothing` type:

```
val a = new Distance(10, new Inch)                                         

println(foo(a, a))                                                               

> scala test.scala

 found   : this.Distance[Nothing]                                   
 required: this.Distance[this.Cm]                                   
Note: Nothing <: this.Cm, but class Distance is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)                   
println(foo(a, a))                                                  
            ^                                                       
one error found
```

Following the compiler's suggestion results in foo returning `10.0inch,10.0inch` rather than the expected `3.93cm,3.93cm`.

If I explicitly specify the type, the compiler picks up on the difference, but still doesn't implicitly convert one to the other.

```
val a = new Distance[Inch](10, new Inch)

println(foo(a, a))                      

// found   : this.Distance[this.Inch]    
// required: this.Distance[this.Cm]      
//  println(foo(a, a))                     
//              ^                          
//  one error found
```

Am I doing something wrong, or does the compiler not allow this usage of implicit conversion?

Comment: First of all: why does `Distance` class have type parameter `A` to begin with? You don't seem to use it anywhere...

Comment: @ghik Whoops, I was using A in my actual code and must've accidentally taken it out when constructing this example. Fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to

```
class Distance[A <: BaseUnit](val scalar: Double, val unit: A) { ... }
```

so that the compiler has a reason to not make `A` too specific.  Otherwise it's free to choose `Nothing` since it's not related to anything that you're doing.

Also, you know how to convert between units, but you haven't taught it how to convert between distances.  You can:

```
implicit def convertDist[A <: BaseUnit, B <: BaseUnit](da: Distance[A])(implicit a2b: (A => B)): Distance[B] = new Distance[B](da.scalar, a2b(da.unit))
```

or something like that.  (As you define it now, the conversions are backwards, incidentally.)

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it! Unfortunately not using `A` was a typo when constructing the example from the real, broken code. Please could you explain what you mean by "As you define it now, the conversions are backwards, incidentally."?

Comment: @Matt - 10 inches is not 3.93 centimeters, but that's what a natural conversion gives.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks, I think I've been staring at this computer for too long!